# Popping sounds when recording screen with FFmpeg

Tags: alsa, chromium, ffmpeg, loop-device, xvfb

I am using FFmpeg (X11Grab and Alsa) to record a virtual screen. I have an Ubuntu server, and I am using xvfb as virtual frame buffer. I launch a browser process using Puppeteer, and record it using the following command:

```
ffmpeg -f alsa -i hw:1,1,0 -video_size 1920x1080 -framerate 30 -f x11grab -draw_mouse 0 -i ${xvfb._display} -c:v libx264rgb -crf 0 -preset ultrafast -color_range 2 ./public/${fileName}.mp4
```

I am using alsa's loopback device to first pipe the audio to alsa using `chromium args (--alsa-output-device=hw:1,0,0)` and then record it. Video recording is working perfectly, but audio recording has some popping sounds.